# HTML, CSS, Bootstrap - Horizontally align texts of different divs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the `container-lg` class of Bootstrap, and I am experiencing the current situation:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="container-lg">
        <h1>Brand</h1>
      </div>
    </header>
    
    <main>
      <div class="row py-5" style="height: 400px;">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <h2>Left</h2>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: red;"></div>
      </div>
    </main>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to horizontally align the text of the left div with the header's one, without affecting to the right container, which **must have a width of 100% without paddings or margins**.

This is what I have tried:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="container-lg">
        <h1>Brand</h1>
      </div>
    </header>
    
    <main>
      <div class="container-lg py-5">
        <div class="row" style="height: 400px;">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <h2>Left</h2>
          </div>
        
          <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: red;"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But, as you can notice, this is not my expected behavior, because it affects to the right container.

Any ideas?

Comment: Note: applying `margin-right: 0` to the parent container doesn't work, because it moves the left text to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, enjoy both of the worlds by using absolute positioning. It's not that awful.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container-lg">
      <h1>Brand</h1>
    </div>
  </header>

  <main>
    <div class="containers-container position-relative">
      <div class="container-fluid-lg">

        <div class="row py-5" style="height: 400px;">
          <div class="col-md-6">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: red;">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="container-lg position-absolute" style="left:0; right:0; top:0;">

        <div class="row py-5" style="height: 400px;">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <h2>Left</h2>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6">
            <h2>Right</h2>


          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </main>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```